# how to build material2 collapsible menu

Tags: typescript

I did not find a solution to build the side menu as the image.
Is there a way to use components from the library?
Sorry my english

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use the component accordion but it did not go well

Comment: So you should start asking why it ddn't go well